# Filtering some random signal using Autoregressive (AR) filter in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, filter, signal-processing, moving-average, autoregressive-models

In MATLAB, If I've some signal `x` let say

```
x = rand(1,1000)
```

and I want to generate `y` by filtering `x` using Autoregressive (AR) filter of order `M`. How can I find `y(n)`? as autoregressive filter needs past values of output for calculation, but I don't have any past output yet. I only have input samples `x`.

In Moving average (MA) filter I can generate `y(n)` easily because it only needs past inputs which I can provide easily because we have `x`, as follows

```
for n=1:1000
  sum=0;
  for k=1:M+1
    if (n-k+1>0)
      sum = sum + (1/M)*x(n-k+1); % MA depends on current & previous input 
    end
  end
  y(n)=sum;
end
```

Can anyone please help me to generate the same for the Autoregressive filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the moving average filter you show you are essentially able to compute the output by using the assumption that past input samples before the first provided value in `x(1)` were zeros.

Similarly, for an autoregressive filter you may compute the output by making the assumption that past outputs before the first computed value `y(1)` are zeros:

```
for n=1:1000

  % Add feedforward section for ARMA filter
  % ... for an AR filter this is just sum=x(n)
  sum = x(n);

  % Feedback section      
  for k=2:M+1   % normalized AR (assuming a(1) equals 1) 
    if (n-k+1>0)
      sum = sum + a(k)*y(n-k+1);
    end
  end
  y(n) = sum;
end
```

More generally, you can also compute the output by seeding the filter with some previous known initial-conditions (though in your particular case you indicate that those initial-conditions aren't known).

Comment: Thanks i got it, can u please answer me how to find these filter taps: a(k)?
Is it necessary to use Yule walker eq to find a(k) or there's some other way out?

Comment: Finding the taps `a(k)` amounts to [digital filter design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_design#Digital_filters). There are many ways to go about it, from trial&error pole placement to least square methods. Yule-Walker equations are a way to estimate `a(k)` given some data sequence (which could also be used as a filter design method).

Comment: @ SleuthEye: can you the help me in answering a kind of similar question? even few hints will be highly appreciated http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/27494/filtering-a-signal-using-autoregressive-ar-filter-and-finding-the-coeff-of-ar